# Is polling events compulsory for an OpenGL SDL 2.0 application?

Tags: c++, opengl, event-handling, sdl-2

I ran into this issue, recently, where I created an OpenGL ES 2.0 context, with SDL 2.0 and I realized that OpenGL does not render anything if `SDL_PollEvent` is not called, after a draw call.

Here is my code:

```
// After creating a valid OpenGL context
// Compiling & linking shaders, and using program...


float vertices[9] = {
       0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
       0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
       -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f
   }; 
   uint32_t vbo; 
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW); 
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos);
    glVertexAttribPointer(pos, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3*sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    
    bool run = true;
    SDL_Event e;
    while (run)
    {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
      SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window); 
  // if SDL_PollEvent is called here, everything works!!! 
   }
```

But, if I call `SDL_PollEvent`  after the window swap function, I see a triangle, **otherwise** , a triangle simply flashes and vanishes out into a blank screen when my application starts.

I want to know what is happening under the hood, that is causing this behaviour!?

I also tried putting a `printf("Running\n");` in the while loop, to check if the loop is running or stuck, and I find it is running indefinitely and making draw calls, but I can't see the triangle...

Vertex Shader:

```
precision mediump float; 
attribute vec3 pos;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0); 
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
precision mediump float; 
void main()
{
      gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0); 
}
```

The operating system is Android, but I expect this is going to happen on other OSes as well ...

Comment: OS?  Window manager?  SDL version?  A [mcve]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know what is happening under the hood, that is causing this behaviour!?

Whenever a process fails to call back into one of the SDL event processing functions (`SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_WaitEvent()`/`SDL_PumpEvents()`) in a timely manner the OS/windowing system will generally consider the process frozen and stop showing window updates.

This sort of draw-then-block behavior (as far as the event system is concerned) sometimes used to work in old single-buffered windowing systems but is pretty iffy nowadays as you've discovered.

Comment: Thankyou very much, I'm trying to make, the  OpenGL part a separate thread, and the polling event part another thread, but it seems impossible with SDL. because SDL wants the event polling to be in the thread that initializes it via ```SDL_Init``` ! :(

Comment: Please can you clarify on the "draw-then-block" behaviour!!!

Comment: @VivekanandV it's basically "draw, present, delay for 5 seconds, and expect thing to be on screen during that time". And nowadays mostly it isn't. This question gets asked a lot here, probably because there are some very popular examples out there that aren't getting fixed. You have a bit different problem, I suppose your mention of delay is confusing as it isn't clear what you're doing.

Comment: @keltar I removed the mention of delay. I understand event polling is necessary, otherwise the OS will assume, my application is hanging. Since, the ```render``` function takes a lot of time (w.r.t the OS) to complete, the events dont get processed during that time frame. Therefore my application loses its smoothness in usage, and OS thinks it's not responding. I cannot render OpenGL in a separate thread and poll events in another, because of SDL limitations!

Comment: @VivekanandV I'm fairly sure it is possible with using GL context on second thread, but you'll still need to synchronise present. How long your render takes? Usually you have few seconds to respond to redraw event, it isn't *that* bad. And if your render takes e.g. 10 seconds then I have my doubts just having separate thread would be enough. But that is a separate question.

Comment: @keltar I have tried setting up GL context, from separate thread and doing all the rendering from the second thread, but, still I get the same result. The triangle is not rendered, it simply flashes out...